# CSS :before not working as expected

Tags: css

I have a "before" element showing a > before a menu item.

You can see it at:
http://jsfiddle.net/EaTz7/

Now what I wish to create is that the > is shown on hover **and** when it's visited, but not when it's unvisited

Only thing is, the

```
li a:visited:before
{
    content: ">";
    color: #b2c900;
}
```

doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

The hover element does work as it is supposed to do.
What am I doing wrong? Or is this functionality just not implemented?

Comment: What's with the inconsistent use of `::before` and `:before`? You should pick only one depending on whether you need IE8 support or not (it doesn't support `::before`)... not that that would be relevant to your question of course.

Comment: the jsfiddle seems to be working on based on your description of requirements in my Opera browser.  As you have a fair bit of code in the jsfiddle (more than shown above), please let us know what exactly the issue is.

Comment: It makes certain CSS selectors act as though links are always unvisited, even when they are visited. http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy

Comment: I already described the exact issue. It's not showing the > on a visted link.

Comment: @BoltClock :: defaults to :link:

Comment: No it doesn't. The double colon is CSS3's pseudo-element notation, and a `:` by itself doesn't automatically mean `:link`.

Comment: Well, it defaults to it in every browser I try.

Comment: Not really... `:link` stands for unvisited link, not just any link or default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct. Here's the problem -> http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Due to privacy related issues (if visited links have this look then I can know the user has visited this site) browsers have limited the number of ways you can style visited links.

Comment: Okay... kinda totally defeats the visted option, but thank you.

Comment: I have always questioned this decision: color is the most common way of visually checking whether a link is visited or not. What's the point of disabling other styles yet retaining at least one that will give it away anyway? If the API wants to lie when queried for the computed style, that's fine, but canceling other styles visually makes no sense. In any case, this is the right answer.

Comment: Yes. I guess having different text colors among a webpage is more common than having, as in this case, a content :before style. Anyway, it seems there could be better ways of handling the issue as some people suggested in the comments of mozillas blog post... perhaps, and probably, not.

Comment: @BoltClock: I think it's to prevent timing attacks. For example `a:visited:before { /* something complex like a gradient or content: a very long string */ }` would take longer to render (might be a terrible example, I'm just guessing).